# Get original email headers of forwarded email using domain-wide-delegation

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api, service-accounts

We have all spam and phishing emails being forwarded to an IT department for review. We currently have individuals downloading the original email in their gmail inbox and then attaching it to an email to the spam box. This has caused a lot of complaints from less technical users.

I am trying to build a python script that can read forwarded emails and then use domain wide delegation to access their email boxes and retrieve the original headers of the forwarded message.

Do any of the fields in the gmail headers stay constant when forwarding an email so that a forwarded email can be used to query the original email in a users inbox ?

The current method that I have tried reads the message ID's of the spam box, retrieves the message, identifies the sender and messageID's of the messages in the spam box and then uses domain-wide-delegation to query the mailbox of the sender for the original message.  This fails however as Gmail messageID's and threadID's of the forwarded emails don't match the original email.

Comment: welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  we need to see your code and a description of the issue with your code.